# Trouble finding frequency of words from a file in C

Tags: c, file, frequency

I need to write a code that will print the frequency of each word from a given file. Words like "the" and "The" will count as two different words. I've written some code so far but the command prompt stops working when I try to run the program. I just need some guidance and to be pointed in the best direction for this code, or I would like to be told that this code needs to be abandoned. I'm not very good at this so any help would be very appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE_NAME "input.txt"

struct word {
    char wordy[2000];
    int frequency;
} words;

int word_freq(const char *text, struct word words[]);

int main (void)
{
    char *text;
    FILE *fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    fread(text, sizeof(text[0]), sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]), fp);
    struct word words[2000];
    int nword;
    int i;
    nword = word_freq(text, words);
    puts("\nWord frequency:");
    for(i = 0; i < nword; i++)
        printf(" %s: %d\n", words[i].wordy, words[i].frequency);
    return 0;
}

int word_freq(const char *text, struct word words[])
{
    char punctuation[] =" .,;:!?'\"";
    char *tempstr;
    char *pword; 
    int nword;
    int i;
    nword = 0;
    strcpy(tempstr, text);
    while (pword != NULL) {
        for(i = 0; i < nword; i++) {
            if (strcmp(pword, words[i].wordy) == 0)
            break;
        }
        if (i < nword)
            words[i].frequency++;
        else { 
            strcpy(words[nword].wordy, pword);
            words[nword].frequency= 1;
            nword++;
         }
         pword = strtok(NULL, punctuation);
    }
    return nword;
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" usually doesn't qualify as a good description of your problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To have the best chance of getting useful answers your question needs to be reasonably specific. Please take some time to go through the [StackOverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Start with something simpler, like open a file, read a line at time, print each line, close the file. Be sure to check the return value from `fopen` to make sure that it succeeded. You can use `fgets` to read a line at a time.

Comment: When I try to run the code through the command prompt, I am given a dialogue box that states it has stopped working. I don't know how else to word that.

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger?  If not, add printf statements throughout your code to determine how far into execution it goes before failing.

Answer (score 1):

First off all:

```
char *text;
FILE *fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
fread(text, sizeof(text[0]), sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]), fp);
```

Reads probably 4 bytes of your file because `sizeof(text[0])` is 1 and `sizeof(text)` is probably 4 (depending on pointer size).  You need to use `ftell()` or some other means to get the actual size of your data file in order to read it all into memory.

Next, you are storing this information into a pointer that has no memory allocated to it.  `text` needs to be malloc'd or made to hold memory in some way.  This is probably what is causing your program to fail to work, just to start.

There are so so SO many further issues that it will take time to explain them:

- How you are using strcpy to blow up memory when you place it into`tempstr`
- How even if that weren't the case, it would copy probably the whole file at once, unless the file had `NULL` terminated strings within, which it may, so perhaps this is ok.
- How you compare `nwords[i].wordy`, even though it is not initialized and therefore garbage.
- How, even if your file were read into memory correctly, you look a `pword`, which is unitialized for your loop counter.

Please, get some help or ask your teacher about this because this code is seriously broken.